# Keeping lines repeated a set number of times

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort, uniq, duplicate

I have a file with multiple columns and have identified lines where values in column 3 have been duplicated.

**Example Input:**

```
A B C
1 2 APPLE
3 4 PEAR
9 3 LEMON
8 3 ORANGE
8 2 APPLE
3 4 APPLE
9 3 LEMON
8 3 PEAR
```

I can count how often the word in Column 3 has been repeated using:

```
awk '{print $3}' [input filename] | sort | uniq -c > [output filename]
```

**Output:**

```
3 APPLE
2 PEAR
2 LEMON
1 ORANGE
```

What I would like to do is keep lines that are repeated 3 times:

**Desired Output:**

```
APPLE
```

or

```
1 2 APPLE
8 2 APPLE
3 4 APPLE
```

I don't mind if all of the columns are printed from the original input file or just the 3rd column value.

Using `sort -u` prints out any line that has appeared at least once which is not what I'm after.

Comment: At least three times or exactly three times?

Comment: If *exactly* 3 times, you can just pipe into `grep '^3'` before you send to file.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to go over the file twice, first to build a reference and the second to filter as needed

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++; next} a[$3]==3' ip.txt ip.txt 
1 2 APPLE
8 2 APPLE
3 4 APPLE

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++; next} a[$3]==2' ip.txt ip.txt 
3 4 PEAR
9 3 LEMON
9 3 LEMON
8 3 PEAR

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$3]++; next} a[$3]<2' ip.txt ip.txt 
A B C
8 3 ORANGE
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

-- to output only entries which occur ***at least*** 3 times:

```
awk '++a[$3]==3{ print $3 }' file
```

- `++a[$3]` - consecutively incremented number of unique values of the 3rd field

---

-- to output only entries which occur ***exactly*** 3 times:

```
awk '{++a[$3]}END{ for(i in a) if(a[i]==3) print i }' file
```

---

The output:

```
APPLE
```

Comment: @Philippos, ok, see my update

Comment: The first version can be done more simple by slightly changing your first attempt. I hope you don't mind that I edited your answer in this way.

Comment: @Philippos, ok, and your 1st comment is obsolete

Comment: Okay, removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the output of your pipeline through `awk '$1 == 3 { print $2 }'` to get just `APPLE`.

Alternatively, count with `awk` from the start:

```
awk '{ c[$3]++; r[$3] = r[$3] ? r[$3] ORS $0 : $0 } END { for (i in c) { if (c[i] == 3) print r[i] } }' file
1 2 APPLE
8 2 APPLE
3 4 APPLE
```

The `awk` script will count, in `c`, how many times the values in column 3 occurs. Each input line is appended to `r` which is an associative array, like `c`, keyed on the third column.

At the end, only lines whose 3rd column occurs exactly three times are outputted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe not the most elegant way but what follows works. It extends what you already did by parsing each line to **filter out those that have an occurrences count not strictly greater than 2**.

```
awk '{print $3}' yourInputFile | sort | uniq -c | while read -r line
   do 
      echo $line | [ `awk '{print $1}'` -gt 2 ] && echo $line | awk '{print $2}'
   done
```

And should you wish to restrict the display to **lines that have an occurrences count strictly equal to 3**, it's even simpler. A `grep` can be used as `@wvxvw` suggested in comments. You don't even need to iterate in that case but you have to shield the `grep` not to get values that begin by 3 but that are greater, such as 30:

```
awk '{print $3}' yourInputFile | sort | uniq -c | grep '^\s*3\s' | awk '{print $2}'
```

In both cases the output is:

```
APPLE
```