# Finding duplicates with first 12 characters of each line

Tags: text-processing

I have file look like this...

```
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
xyz200300300 aelmi
```

How do I print the lines that have duplicates (based on examining just the first 12 characters) to a separate file?

so in the separate file I should have

```
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
```

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394731/keeping-lines-repeated-a-set-number-of-times

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if it's a standard option, or a GNU extension but if your `uniq` has a `-w` flag:

```
   -w, --check-chars=N
          compare no more than N characters in lines
```

So

```
sort file | uniq -D -w12
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
```

or, redirected to a new file

```
sort file | uniq -D -w12 > newfile
```

Comment: both `-w` and `-D` are GNU extensions.busybox uniq has -w but not -D

Comment: (note that with current unpatched versions of GNU `uniq` (and busybox'), it's no more than N _bytes_, not _characters_. For instance with `-w1`, it would say that `á` and `é` are duplicates in UTF-8 locales because the encoding of those two characters start with the same byte.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
cut -c -12 file | uniq -d | grep -f - file
```

Extract the 1st 12 characters, get duplicate ones, and get the lines matching the duplicate pattern.

Comment: `uniq` expects sorted input.  @logger didn't say whether the file is sorted or unsorted, so best to assume it's not sorted.  `cut -c -12 file | sort | uniq -d > newfile`.  Dunno why you had the pipe to `grep -f` - the "separate file" that was mentioned is an output file for the dupe list, not a list of patterns to match.

Comment: That `grep -f` will search for those _duplicated_ strings (actually consider them as regular expressions) everywhere in the lines so could give you false positives, false negatives and would be generally quite inefficient on large input.

Answer (score 1):

**`sort`** + **`awk`** solution (for 2-field lines):

Sample `input.txt`:

```
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
xyz200300300 aelmi
wwwunix&linx good
wwwunix&linx fine
wwwunix&linx great
someotherone other
```

---

```
sort input.txt | awk '$1==f1{ if ($1!=prev) print f1,f2; print }{ prev=f1; f1=$1; f2=$2 }'
```

The output:

```
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
wwwunix&linx fine
wwwunix&linx good
wwwunix&linx great
```

---

GNU **`awk`** version:

```
awk '{ a[$1][++c]=$2; if(!$1 in a) c=0 }
     END{ for (k in a) 
              if (length(a[k]) > 1) { 
                  for (i in a[k]) print k,a[k][i] 
              } 
     }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A double-pass approach with GNU `awk` that preserves the order in the input file:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS=12 '
  ARGIND == 1 {c[$1]++; next}
  FNR == 1 {for (i in c) if (c[i] < 2) delete c[i]}
  $1 in c' inputFile inputFile
```

The POSIX equivalent:

```
awk '
  {key = substr($0, 1, 12)}
  !first_pass_done {c[key]++; next}
  FNR == 1 {for (i in c) if (c[i] < 2) delete c[i]}
  key in c' inputFile first_pass_done=1 inputFile
```

Comment: the double pass is interesting - but since you are already building an array - couldnt you just parse the array in `END`?

Comment: @StevenPenny, preserving the order would be trickier though. It would also mean storing more of the file (than the unique keys) in memory.

Answer (score -1):

I have done by using below awk and sed command

Inputfile

```
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
xyz200300300 aelmi
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `awk '{print substr($1,1,12)}' Inputfile | sort | uniq`
do
j=`sed -n "/$i/p" Inputfile| wc -l`
if [[ $j > 1 ]]
then
sed -n "/$i/p" Inputfile>> /var/tmp/new_file_duplicate.txt
fi
done
```

New_file_duplicate.txt contains below content

```
abc100200300 abmen
abc100200300 arcxi
```