# How to get lines from unique columns?

Tags: awk, sort, uniq

I have a single ascii file (Report.dat) with these lines:

```
a  ./L1/file2.txt
c  ./L1/file1.txt
b  ./L2/file1.txt
a  ./L2/file2.txt
```

and I need to get just the lines where the first column is unique, as follows:

```
c  ./L1/file1.txt
b  ./L2/file1.txt
```

How can I do that using AWK, sort or uniq commands ?

Comment: opposite of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394731/keeping-lines-repeated-a-set-number-of-times

Comment: does the 1st column always consist of 1 char?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - no, it's in fact a long alphanumeric string.

Comment: Excellent reference @Sundeep,  yes ,it seems to be the opposite.  :)

Comment: @LeMike but is it a *fixed length* alphanumeric string? if it is, then at least with GNU `uniq` you could use `sort Report.dat | uniq -uwN` where `N` is the length of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get the "labels" that are unique:

```
$ awk '{ print $1 }' Report.dat | sort | uniq -u
b
c
```

These can be converted to regular expressions that match at the start of the line by adding `^` in front of the strings:

```
$ awk '{ print $1 }' Report.dat | sort | uniq -u | sed 's/^/^/'
^b
^c
```

You can apply these regular expressions to the original file to get the corresponding lines:

```
$ awk '{ print $1 }' Report.dat | sort | uniq -u | sed 's/^/^/' | grep -f /dev/stdin Report.dat
c  ./L1/file1.txt
b  ./L2/file1.txt
```

With `grep -f /dev/stdin` we tell `grep` to take the regular expressions coming from `sed` and use these to do matching in `Report.dat`.

---

Alternatively, to bypass the `sed` step:

```
awk '{ print "^" $1 }' Report.dat | sort | uniq -u | grep -f /dev/stdin Report.dat
```

---

Alternatively, do it all in `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { c[$1]++; next } c[$1] == 1' Report.dat Report.dat
```

This reads the file twice.  The first time around, it simply counts the number of time that each "label" occurs.  The second time around, it tests the label on the current line to see if its count is one before printing the line.

Note that there is no way around parsing the file twice.  One could store the complete file in memory and parse it twice there, but that's fiddly and will be problematic *in the general case* when we don't know how large files we are feeding into the script.

Comment: Excellent!!! @Kusalananda! It works fine!, and could be possible to show the lines where the first column exists more than once too ?

Comment: @LeMike This would possibly be simplest with the last variation using only `awk`.  Just change `==` to `>`.

Comment: Thanks very much @Kusalananda!, I'm very much grateful for your help!.